# How to validate user inputs which comes both from parent component and child component before submitting data using save button in parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component "Parent" and a child component "Child" which is called in the parent component on click of an anchor tag through router link.
there are two user inputs in the parent component and two user inputs in child component. A save button is included in the parent component. How can I validate if the user has entered data in both the parent and child component so that I can validate and save the user inputs?

Parent Component Template:

```
<img src="save.png"(click)="validateandsave(model)">
<input type="text" name="code" [(ngModel)]="model.code">
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name">
<a routerLink="PC">
<div (click)="showsettings()"> </div>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

ParentComponent ts file:

```
showsettings() 
{ 
    this.router.navigate(['PC'], { relativeTo: this.route }); 
}
validateandsave()
{
    /*how to implement since i have inputs in child component as well*/
}
```

Child component template:

```
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" [(ngModel)]="phonenumber">
<input type="text" name="address" [(ngModel)]="address">
```

How can I validate if the user has entered data in all four inputs(from parent and child)?so that I can save the data

app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
        path: 'enter',
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [

          {
            path: 'PC',
            component: ChildComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: hey, is this enough?

Comment: Code snippet doesn't match based on your question, where is the `child component` in your `parent component`?

Comment: hey is it fine now? Sorry, I didnt upload app.routing module earlier

Comment: child form fields only show when you go to that page right?

Comment: yea...they show up in the router-outlet when you click that anchor tag

Comment: you want that fields to be included in parent form right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can register your child form field with parent form using controlcontainer. First you should wrap you router-outlet inside your form tag.

```
<form #f="ngForm"> 
 Email:<input type="text" ngModel name="email">
<br>
 Name:<input type="text" ngModel name="name">
 <a routerLink='pc'>Next</a>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</form>
```

Then Use viewproviders to provide control container and use existing form.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pc',
  templateUrl: './pc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pc.component.css'],
  viewProviders:[{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
})
export class PcComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9z52wq

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot... but is this the only way possible??? because I cant do this...because I have other divs that shouldn't be in the form...it would mess up my ui..

Comment: can't you place the div outside the form?

Comment: Hey..I was being an idiot...I could just put all divs inside the form.....Thanks a lot

Comment: @Chellappan Hey ...How can I do validation in this at html side??

Comment: <small *ngIf="f&&f.get('name')&&f.get('name').hasError('required')">Required!</small>      
I tried like this ..but console throws an error saying "get is not a function"

Comment: can you check this tutorial how to  use validation in template drive form:https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I did look there but it didn’t assess my problem... my submit button is in parent component .... so suppose the form name is f... then I am checking f.submitted is true before validating any fields.... I cannot get the f.submitted value in the router outlet child component.... how can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean yiu want to know the submit property inside child form?

Comment: yea...because i wanna use that in validation..Is it possible?

Comment: yes you can inject controlcontainer in child component and you can access all the parent form controls